# Gauss-Seidel Method exceeds Machine Numbers?

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Happy New Year everyone! :)

I'm writing a Gauss-Seidel function in Matlab and I'm encountering some problems.

The iteration must stop when we reach 6 decimal digits of precision. It means that the infinite norm (asked to use it) of `x-xprevious` must be less than `0.5*10^(-6)`.
Firstly, here's my function:

```
function [x] = ex1_3(A,b)

format long 

sizeA=size(A,1);

x=zeros(sizeA,1);  

%Just a check for the conditions of the Gauss-Seidel Method
for i=1:sizeA
    sum=0;
    for j=1:sizeA
        if i~=j 
            sum=sum+A(i,j);
        end
    end
    if A(i,i)<sum
        fprintf('\nGauss-Seidel''s conditions not met!\n');
        return     
    end
end

%Actual Gauss-Seidel Method

max_temp=10^(-6); %Pass first iteration
while max_temp>(0.5*10^(-6))
    xprevious=x;
    for i=1:sizeA
        x(i,1)=b(i,1);
        for j=1:sizeA
            if i~=j
              x(i,1)=x(i,1)-A(i,j)*x(j,1); 
            end
        end
        x(i,1)=x(i,1)/A(i,i);
    end
    x
    %Calculating infinite norm of vector x-xprevious 

    temp=x-xprevious;
    max_temp=temp(1,1);
    for i=2:sizeA
       if abs(temp(i,1))>max_temp
           max_temp=abs(temp(i,1));
       end
    end
end
```

And now the problems! When I call the function for a 3x3 array, I think it works. However, when I call it for a 10x10 array `x` becomes `Inf` (I guess it's out of machine numbers limits). Is there anything I can do to prevent this, except for changing the infinite norm and the 6 decimal digits precision (I must use these two, because my tutor told me so) ?

In the array I use (which was given to me) the entries outside the diagonal are `-1` and the ones on the diagonal are `3`. `b` is like this `b=[2;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;2]` (for `n=10`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition of the Gauss-Seidel Method is not correct:

```
D=diag(diag(A));
L=-tril(A,-1);U=-triu(A,1);
B=(D-L)\U;
R = max(abs(eig(B)));
if R>=1
    fprintf('\nGauss-Seidel''s conditions not met!\n');
    return     
end
```

`R` is called spectral radius of iterative matrix `B`. It has to be less than 1 that Gauss-Seidel converges. Actually the matrix A in your test case has the `R=1.8092`, thus Gauss-Seidel method won't converge.

Check this [slide](http://www.math.ust.hk/~mamu/courses/231/Slides/CH07_3B.pdf) from page 18 for more details.

**EDIT**

According to @LutzL's comment, you may use [Gershgorin circle theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem#Example) to estimate the eigenvalue rather than calculate them with computational cost.

Comment: Well, it could be correct as stated. He only has to use absolute values everywhere to check for diagonal dominance. See Gershgorin circle theorem. -- And what is the use of an iterative solver if the first step is to compute the eigen-decomposition of the matrix? Then one can also just invoke the internal (sparse) solver of matlab via `x=A\b`.

Comment: I saw your comments, about my matrix not having diagonal dominance or accepted spectral radius and I suspected I may have created the matrix wrongly. I was true. I re-read the exercise and I realised I got it wrong at first! Thank you for your help both!

Comment: Plus, I put the abs() in my checking! Thank you LutzL!

Comment: The test for diagonal dominance ensures that according to the Gerschgorin theorem all eigenvalues are different from zero resp. positive. Note that the method can still converge even if the dominance test fails, since the Gershgorin circles are rather coarse enclosures of the eigenvalues.